# Trying to understand notation conventional from set theory book

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am reading *Introduction to set theory by Karel Hrbacek* [image]

**What I understand:** In order to define an object (introduce notation) is advisable to prove both its existence and uniqueness because that way we'll have no doubt what object the notation stands for and defining something that doesn't exist wouldn't be of much use.

**What I don't understand:**

- Context: In the book the authors state the axiom schema of comprehension (or of separation in other textbooks as follows:

> $ \forall A: \exists B: \forall x: \Big(x\in B\iff x\in A \wedge \varphi(x)\Big)$ where $\varphi(x)$ is a property of $x$.

Then they showed the set $B$ from above is unique. Now they can name it $\{x\in A:\varphi(x)\}$

- **The nitty gritty for me:** In the snippet they name, now, the set $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$ as $\{x: \varphi(x)\}$ and I know that's the notation for class and that every set is a class but not every class is a set. But

1. **why are they proving the existence of $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$ again if we already know it does?** and **
2. **By proving $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}=\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\}$ aren't they proving that the set is unique which we already knew?**

Comment: 1) The are *not* proving it again.  They are stating that as it does exist and it does not depend on $A$ we can give it a label and refer to this set as $\{x|P(x)\}$. 2) You did *not* already know it was unique.  The told you it was unique and *now* they are asking you to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

The previous proof you are referring to shows that the witness to the $“\exists B”$ in the axiom is unique and thus that $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$ is well-defined for any $A$. But the issue at hand is not that, it is the well-definedness of the set $ \{x:\varphi(x)\}$ under the assumption that there is a set $A$ such that $\forall x\;(\varphi(x)\to x\in A).$ These are different ideas.

Comment: So that means they are proving "again" the existence and uniqueness of $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$ because it is  donde under a differente axiom than the axiom's so doing so is not redundant ?

Comment: I deleted the comment you're relating to and posted a different one. Please check that!

Comment: @Replik No. They do state that that set exists (which is indeed already known from separation) but what follows isn’t the assertion that it is unique, but rather the assertion that (under the given conditions) it doesn’t depend on $A$. That has nothing to do with the uniqueness of the bounded comprehension and everything to do with the well-definedness of the unbounded comprehension.

Comment: So, how come can they introduce the notation $\{x: \varphi(x)\}$ for $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$ if they're not proving the latter exists and it's unique ?

Comment: Could we continue this conversation on chat?, I've not been able to understand this snippet.

Comment: (which they’ve defined as the bounded comprehension for *some* $A$ satisfying the condition).

Comment: How does one know then a set is well-defined ?

Comment: I added a parenthetical to the end that is maybe clarifying. Go ahead and open a chat if you want. That set (the bounded one) is well-defined, sure, but like you say, that’s already established. The point is they are dropping the specific $A$, and saying that any $A$ satisfying the condition will work and give the same resulting set (provided such an $A$ exists).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133574/discussion-between-replik-and-spaceisdarkgreen).